# Merge two 2d arrays according to a shared column value and modify keys while appending elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have the following two arrays of objects:
**First Array:** `$array1`

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [match] => 1
            [when] => 2013-10-13 15:00:00
            [a] => AD
            [b] => NiP
            [winner] => c
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => Fragbite Masters
            [format] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [match] => 2
            [when] => 2013-10-13 15:00:00
            [a] => VG
            [b] => AD
            [winner] => a
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => Starseries
            [format] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [match] => 3
            [when] => 2013-10-13 21:15:00
            [a] => Serbia
            [b] => Portugal
            [winner] => a
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => ESEC
            [format] => 1
        )

)
```

**Second Array:** `$array2`

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [match] => 1
            [a] => 58
            [b] => 107
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [match] => 2
            [a] => 174
            [b] => 162
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [match] => 3
            [a] => 64
            [b] => 59
        )

)
```

**I would like to get something like this:**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [match] => 1
            [when] => 2013-10-13 15:00:00
            [a] => AD
            [b] => NiP
            [winner] => c
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => Fragbite Masters
            [format] => 3
            [per_a] => 58
            [per_b] => 107
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [match] => 2
            [when] => 2013-10-13 15:00:00
            [a] => VG
            [b] => AD
            [winner] => a
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => Starseries
            [format] => 5
            [per_a] => 174
            [per_b] => 162
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [match] => 3
            [when] => 2013-10-13 21:15:00
            [a] => Serbia
            [b] => Portugal
            [winner] => a
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => ESEC
            [format] => 1
            [per_a] => 64
            [per_b] => 59
        )

)
```

Where the key name `[a]` and `[b]` from the second array have been modified to `[per_a]` and `[per_b]`.

> **Things i tried to merge both files:**
>   **array_merge & array_merge_recursive**: both get me a result where the merged values of `$array2` are appended to the end of `$array1`.
>   **array_combine**: Wont work because `$array1` and `$array2` haven't an equal number of elements.

This is just a part of each file, both are not equal in term of elements.
If you have an answer for me it would be apreciated ! thx in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you need to modify your keys in function. see [**Demo**](https://ideone.com/IyaRio)

> `$match` : will check key exists in both arrays. `$whereKey1` 
>   `$whereKey2` : pick up the values from second array and put it in your
>   new key which `$newkey1` and `$newkey2`

```
function key_compare_func($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $newarray = array();
    $match = "match";
    $whereKey1 = "a";
    $whereKey2 = "b";
    $newKey1 = "per_a";
    $newKey2 = "per_b";

    if(is_array($arr1) && is_array($arr2)){
        if($arr1[$match] == $arr2[$match] ){
            $newarray = array_merge($arr1, array($newKey1 => $arr2[$whereKey1], $newKey2 => $arr2[$whereKey2]));
        }
    }
  return $newarray;
}

$modifiedArray = array_map("key_compare_func",$A1, $A2);
echo '<pre>';print_r($modifiedArray);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [match] => 1
            [when] => 2013-10-13 15:00:00
            [a] => AD
            [b] => NiP
            [winner] => c
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => Fragbite Masters
            [format] => 3
            [per_a] => 58
            [per_b] => 107
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [match] => 2
            [when] => 2013-10-13 15:00:00
            [a] => VG
            [b] => AD
            [winner] => a
            [closed] => 1
            [event] => Starseries
            [format] => 5
            [per_a] => 174
            [per_b] => 162
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your second array only hold unique `match` ids, then you can use it as a lookup array after applying the `match` values as first level keys.  `array_column()` makes this task very simple.

Then simply iterate the over the rows in the first array (modifying by reference so that changes to rows are applied to the original array).

Using this technique, it won't matter if the corresponding rows between the two arrays have different original first level keys (the same cannot be said for @Noman's answer which requires each row from the first array to have a cooresponding row with the exact same position in the second array).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uNIlG))

```
$lookup = array_column($A2, null, 'match');
foreach ($A1 as &$row) {
    if (isset($lookup[$row['match']])) {
        $row['per_a'] = $lookup[$row['match']]['a'];
        $row['per_b'] = $lookup[$row['match']]['b'];
    }
}
var_export($A1);
```